# Swagger Editor: Save Changes Back to Source File?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

From the Swagger Editor, can changes or edits be saved back to the original, imported file? Currently, I am saving the code as a yaml file, doing a compare within Intellij, accepting each change, then saving that file. Onerous at best. I'm just changing text in description tags and don't need to make calls, mess with APIs, or servers.

Answer (score 0):

The open-source [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io) has the **File > Save as YAML** command. For best results, configure your browser to ask for the download location and file name instead of automatically saving to the "Downloads" folder.

- Chrome: Open chrome://settings/downloads and select **Ask where to save each file before downloading**.
- Firefox: **Options > General** > scroll down to **Downloads** and select **Always ask you where to save files**.

[SwaggerHub](https://swagger.io/tools/swaggerhub/) (commercial product, has a free plan) combines the editor with cloud storage. It can also sync OpenAPI files with an external Git repository.

There are also [OpenAPI editor plugins](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?search=openapi%20editor) for IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Thanks! My swagger Editor has that File >> Save as YAML option, but it automatically saves to the Downloads folder, not where it came from.

Comment: You can configure your browser to ask for the download location instead of using the "Downloads" folder. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! The details are always appreciated.